# Adding two matrices using OpenMP

Tags: c, matrix, openmp

If I wanted to add two matrices using OpenMP, would I need two sets of parallel conditions like this?

```
void matrix_add(matrix *A, matrix *B, matrix *C) {

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < C->dim.rows; i++) {
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for (int j = 0; j < C->dim.cols; j++) {
            C->data[i][j] = A->data[i][j] + B->data[i][j];
        }
    }

}
```

Or would I only need the parallel condition above the first loop?

Comment: Have you tried both ways to see what happens?

Comment: I have and my guess is the performance difference is perhaps due to j not being private, but I was unsure of the correct syntax. Correction, not performance difference, rather correctness.

Comment: Try to 'manually execute' your program to understand what will happen. If the first directive splits the workload across all available threads, what do you expect the nested directive to do? (Hint: not a whole lot, but test it anyway to be sure.)